# C++ global array allocation

Tags: c++, static, multidimensional-array

I have a C++ global multidimensional array with static linkage. I am assuming it will be stack allocated (I can't find the relevant section in the standard). Is it allocated contiguously?

Another question:
I want to convert these static global n-dim arrays to be allocated on heap. What is the easiest way considering I want to minimize code changes? I can think of converting the arrays to n-dim pointers and malloc'ing at the start of main and free'ing before exiting main. But I have to worry about the contiguous allocation. Anybody see a better way?

Thanks,

Nilesh.

Comment: Why arrays?  How about std::vector?

Comment: @VaughnCato, it's a multidimensional array, so a vetor would not fit.

Comment: You can use std::vector<std:vector<T> >

Comment: @VaughnCato, the elements will not be contiguous in that case. Assuming you have a `vector<vector<int>>`, if you called `data()` on the "top" vector, you would not get a pointer to a continuous chunk of integers, which is what (if I understand correctly) OP wants.

Comment: for a statically sized array: `std::array<std::array<T,Col>,Row>` (or `template<typename T,int Rows,int Cols> using Matrix2D = std::array<std::array<T,Cols>,Rows>; Matrix2D<int,10,20> my_matrix;`)

Answer (score 2):

> I have a C++ global multidimensional array with static linkage. I am assuming it will be stack allocated (I can't find the relevant section in the standard).

It will not be on the stack; it will be in the global area. Globals and static-storage objects get their own region of memory that is not part of the heap nor the stack.

Further, stack (the standard calls it "automatic" storage) objects only last as long as the function call they're part of; globals are initialized before `main()` is called and destroyed after `main()` exits.

> Is it allocated contiguously?

It could be, though I doubt the standard requires it. (Clarification: contiguous storage for a 1-D array is guaranteed, but there's no guarantee there aren't "gaps" between rows in 2-D and up arrays.) If you require contiguous allocation, declare the global array as a one-dimensional vector and use an inline function to convert multiple dimensions to the corresponding index. It's the same as what the compiler would have generated if contiguous storage were guaranteed.

> I want to convert these static global n-dim arrays to be allocated on heap. What is the easiest way considering I want to minimize code changes?

Change the global declaration from being an array to a pointer. In this case, vectorizing the storage is strongly recommended. (No, I'm not talking about `std::vector`, I'm talking about reshaping into a 1-D vector.)

> I can think of converting the arrays to n-dim pointers

No such beast. Closes thing is a pointer to an array of pointers, which then point to either vectors or arrays of more pointers, depth determined by number of dimensions. It would be a bear to set up, and also much slower than, the 1-d vector case above with a function to convert N-D coordinates to a 1-D index.

> malloc'ing at the start of main and free'ing before exiting main.

This, except you don't have to `free` at the end unless you're using `valgrind` or similar to look for memory leaks. The OS frees all your allocations that aren't shared memory upon process exit.

So you get something like:

```
#include <stddef.h>

static const size_t kDimX = 5;
static const size_t kDimY = 20;
static const size_t kDimZ = 4;

inline size_t DimsToVector(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z)
{
    return (x * kDimY + y) * kDimZ + z;
}

float* data = 0;

int main()
{
    data = new float[kDimX * kDimY * kDimZ];

    // Read elements with: data[DimsToVector(x, y, z)]
    // Write v with: data[DimsToVector(x, y, z)] = k;

    delete[] data; // Optional.
}
```

There are fancier ways, probably one in Boost, which define classes and override `operator []` to hide some of the ugly, but this is about the minimum to get you going.

Comment: hmm, this is what I feared. This requires me to change all the references/uses of the array! Although if the original array was not allocated contiguously then I don't have to worry about it in the transformed program. I am just worried that if the programmer is guaranteed contiguous allocation then s/he can basically treat the multi-dimensional arrays as single-dimensional one and so the transformed program also must guarantee contiguous allocation.

Comment: Honestly, unless your elements have some odd element sizes, it's very likely the storage will be contiguous. _But the standard will not have your back._ So you have to choose: go to all this trouble to be compatible with standards, or be pragmatic, test your particular compiler, and look for gaps in storage.

Answer (score 1):

It's not allocated on the stack. Global variables are "allocated" in a special memory segment.

As of making your multidimensional array "contiguous", the simplest surefire way I can think of without fighting too much against the type system is to make a `typedef` of the lower dimension and make a pointer to that type.

```
typedef int TenIntegers[10];
TenIntegers* ints;

int main()
{
    ints = new TenIntegers[50];

    // your code here
    ints[0][5] = 3;

    delete[] ints;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why this is 'contiguous/continuous' allocation, isn't it the same as pointers-to-pointers? Also, will this generalize to ndims > 2?

Comment: @Nilesh, it's not the same as a pointer-to-pointer. It's "hard" to do without a typedef because the C++ syntax is not very gracious; but by using the type `TenIntegers` in this example, you do reference an array of 10 integers. By allocating an array of 50 of them, you effectively have a contiguous set of 500 integers, that you can access through `ints[a][b]`. If you need more dimensions, you can make more typedefs: `typedef TenIntegers TenIntegerArrays[10];`

Answer (score 0):

1) The memory for globals is allocated somewhere "in memory". It is neither on the stack, nor on the heap. For instance, global constants are usually placed in read-only section of the executable. Strictly speaking, it's implementation dependent. Why do you need to know this?

2) Memory will be continuous.

Comment: 1) I was curious about the allocation of these arrays. Do you know if this is how they are allocated in C (I guess they are called file-scope variables in C)?
2) So I don't have to chase pointers for a multidimensional array in that case? Also can you please point me to the appropriate place in the standard where it is mentioned that their storage will be continuous?